# How to integrate the element label into the validation error message in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, view-helpers, zend-validate, validationmessage

I have a form, where the error messages have to be displayed bundled at one place. The default messages are general, so the user sometimes doesn't know, which message is for which form field:

> A record matching the input was found
>
> Value is required and can't be empty
>
> The input is not a valid email address...

I could write a custom message for every field, but is much effort and copy&paste.

So, I'd like to display the messages like this:

> **My element Foo label**: A record matching the input was found
>
> **My element Bar label**: Value is required and can't be empty
>
> **My element Buz label**: The input is not a valid email address...

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 seems not to provide a solution for this requirement. My solution/workaround is to override the `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors` replacing [these lines](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormElementErrors.php#L81-L83) of the `FormElementErrors#render(...)` by

```
$this->prepareMessagesToPrint($messages, $messagesToPrint, $element, $escapeHtml);
```

and add a method, that process the `$messages` as desired:

```
protected function prepareMessagesToPrint($messages, &$messagesToPrint, $element, $escapeHtml) {
    foreach ($messages as $nameOrType => $elementOrError) {
        if (is_string($elementOrError)) {
            $elementLabel = $element->getLabel()
                ? '<b>' . $this->view->translate($element->getLabel()) . '</b>' . ': '
                : null
            ;
            $message = $escapeHtml($elementOrError);
            $messagesToPrint[] = $elementLabel ? $elementLabel . $message : $message;

        } elseif (is_array($elementOrError)) {
            $newElement = $element->get($nameOrType);
            $this->prepareMessagesToPrint(
                $elementOrError, $messagesToPrint, $newElement, $escapeHtml
            );
        }
    }
}
```